# How to control number of childs spawned by nodejs+express in production mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, forever

I am using express JS to run a website. The server is started using the following command.

```
NODE_ENV=production nohup supervisor -w $APP_FILE $APP_FILE >$LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
```

When looked at the process list, I see one parent process and 5 child node processes. I'm just wondering who is spawning these processes and where can I control it?

My `server.js` also starts a background job using `forever`.

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');
var child = new (forever.Monitor)('worker.js', {
    max: 1000,
    silent: false,
    options: []
});

child.start();
```

Interestingly, when running on server, I see multiple instances of `worker.js` running. I need to run only one instance and not sure how to control this.

Screenshot of what I am seeing.

[image]

Comment: I have also noticed that when I run the same command on a local machine, it is not starting all these child processes. Just one `server.js` and one `worker.js`. Not sure why this happens in just the server.

Comment: Can you please print the all the process which are started with node? use **ps -ef |grep -i node** if you are on *nix. I am guessing they are process internally started by supervisor..

Comment: @Sriharsha updated with screenshot

Comment: I can explain it better if you put the screenshot with the pids..

Comment: @Sriharsha pids are all different for each child process.

Comment: Yes, I know but the parent id of the process makes it easy for know which parent process as has forked which one..Without this it will be difficult to answer..